# How to add timepicker to jquery jtable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jtable

I am using jQuery [jTable](http://jtable.org/Demo/MasterChild) in my PHP site to display table and to add a record / modify a record to the table.

I have few fields which have time values. Unfortunately jTable supports only a datepicker, not a timepicker. Can anyone suggest how to add jQuery timepicker to the jTable?

I tried to add few JQuery Time Picker in the main JTable.js file. But I Think i'm adding wrongly. Since i'm new to jquery, i can't figure out how to add the JQuery Time Picker Plugin

```
   <div id="ShiftTableContainer" style="width: 600px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            //Prepare jTable
            $('#ShiftTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Shift',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '../m/ShiftActions.php?action=list',
                    createAction: '../m/ShiftActions.php?action=create',
                    updateAction: '../m/ShiftActions.php?action=update',
                    deleteAction: '../m/ShiftActions.php?action=delete'
                },
                fields: {
                    id: {
                        title: 'Shift Id',
                        width: '25%'
                    },
                    name: {
                        title: 'Shift Name',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    start_time: {
                        title: 'Start Time',
                        width: '75%',
                        input: function (data) {
                                var dt = data.record ? data.record.start_time : NULL;
                                return '<input type="text" style="width:200px" value="' + dt + '" />';
                            }
                        inputClass: 'timepicker'
                    },

                    end_time: {
                        title: 'End Time',
                        width: '75%',

                        //options: { '1': '101', '2': '102' }
                    },
                    description: {
                        title: 'Description',
                        width: '75%'
                    },
                    color: {
                        title: 'Color',
                        width: '75%',
                        //options: { '1': '101', '2': '102' }
                    },
                    break_schedule: {
                        title: 'Break Schedule',
                        width: '75%',
                    }
                }

            });

            $('#ShiftTableContainer').jtable('load');
        });



    </script>
            <script>
            $(function(){
                  $("input.timepicker").datetimepicker();
                });     

    </script>
```

Comment: The order of the scripts are important.  Make sure you add the jquery library first.  Then, the timepicker code must be called inside a document.ready function.  Use Firefox's Error Console to see if you get any javascript errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried like this and its working fine. I updated JQuery and JQuery UI to the latest version. Imported it in my php along with the timepicker plugin i am using. I did some modification in my code. Here is the working code.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            //Prepare jTable
            $('#ShiftTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Shift',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '../m/ShiftActions.php?action=list',
                    createAction: '../m/ShiftActions.php?action=create',
                    updateAction: '../m/ShiftActions.php?action=update',
                    deleteAction: '../m/ShiftActions.php?action=delete'
                },
                fields: {
                    id: {
                        key: true,
                        edit: false,
                        title: 'Shift Id',
                        width: '25%'
                    },
                    name: {
                        title: 'Shift Name',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    start_time: {
                        title: 'Start Time',
                        width: '75%'
                    },

                    end_time: {
                        title: 'End Time',
                        width: '75%'
                    },
                    description: {
                        title: 'Description',
                        width: '75%'
                    },
                    color: {
                        title: 'Color',
                        width: '75%',
                        //options: { '1': '101', '2': '102' }
                    },
                    break_schedule: {
                        title: 'Break Schedule',
                        width: '75%',
                    }
                },
                formCreated: function (event, data) 
                {
                    var $input_start_time = data.form.find ('input[name="start_time"]');
                    $input_start_time.addClass("time");
                    $input_start_time.timepicker();

                    var $input_end_time = data.form.find ('input[name="end_time"]');
                    $input_end_time.addClass("time");
                    $input_end_time.timepicker();

                }
            });

            $('#ShiftTableContainer').jtable('load');

        });



    </script>
```

Comment: still doesn't render for me, still just a normal text field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Timepicker Addon, I have not tested yet but this plugin add a timepicker to the jQueryUI Datepicker.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: I tried it man. Its working when i add a input field in my page, but its not working for me, inside the form. I have to modify in their jtable file. But i think i'm adding the script wrongly. I'm new to jquery thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "input" field (see http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference) for the dateTimePicker. Tie the dateTimepicker to each text input that you use for time, like this:

Give all the time inputs the same class (ex. "timepicker") - see 'inputClass' option from the above api reference' - and then tie the timepicker like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("input.timepicker").datetimepicker();
});
```

Remember to add the [dateTimePicker script](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), and before that also the jQuery as well as jQuery UI (User Interface) libraries.

EDIT in response to comment:

Setup the above timepicker code ***outside*** of the jtable code.  For the jtable, try something like this:

```
Time: {
    title: 'Start Time',
    input: function (data) {
               var dt = data.record ? data.record.Time : '';
               return '<input type="text" style="width:200px" value="' + dt + '" />';
           }
    inputClass: 'timepicker',
etc.
```

Comment: Do i want to add this in the field part?? Example like this? `start_time: {
       title: 'Start Time',
       width: '75%',
       input :  $(function(){
           $("start_time.timepicker").datetimepicker();
         }); 

      },`

Comment: NB: You must use `$("input.timepicker")` or `$(".timepicker")` when you select the `input` elements to be transformed.

Comment: Its not working Stefan. in fact the table itself itself not loading.

Comment: @Allen:  OK, do it in steps.  First get the table working without the datepicker and inputs - first, simply display the time as a value in your Start Time column.  Then, specify that the time values should be inputs. When you have that right, specify the inputClass, and then add the datetimepicker code.

Comment: I was able to display time as string value. But when i add Time picker, its not working. I have added the code in my question.
Check whether you can find my mistakes. Since i'm new to this jquery. i can't find the bug.

Comment: You mean the table stops working? Or do you just mean the timepicker has no effect?

Comment: I missed a comma in the table. Its displaying the table. But the script is not getting executed.

Comment: Did you manage to create the text inputs for the time values?  If those inputs are not there, then the timepicker won't work.

Comment: Ya i created text inputs for the time value.

Comment: Use Firebug to verify that the text inputs have the class `timepicker`.  Then make sure you added all the external scripts, namely jqueryUI and datetimepicker.  Also look at what javascript errors you are getting from the error console.

Comment: Also try the timepicker in Paul Grimshaw's answer above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12837428/888177

Comment: Try this in my code above: `<input type="text" class='timepicker' style="width:200px" value="' + dt + '" />`

Comment: Still i found the same problem. and, my add new record button is not getting displaying the form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17872/discussion-between-allen-and-stefan)

Comment: Hope this helped you - I'll have to get on with my work. (BTW, I think `NULL` should be `null` in js.) Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

My favorite time picker is this jQuery UI timepicker:

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/